# Vista de diseño de un form en VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vscode, vs

Soy novato en vs code.

Cuando creo un nuevo form me lo muestra como en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando abro un proyecto guardado, me lo muestra de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo ver el design view del ultimo formulario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es porque no estás abriendo la solución del proyecto en este caso tu estás abriendo la carpeta, intenta dar doble click sobre Colecciones.sln y te aparecerá como el primer caso